# Using Sed to insert line of text with tab delimiter

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to add a line of text to the top of a text file with tab delimiters.

```
sed -i '1s/^/x,y,z\n/' INPUTFILE.txt
```

^^This of course yields "x,y,z" in the top row of the input file.

```
sed -i '1s/^/x'\t'y'\t'z\n/' INPUTFILE.txt
```

^^This yields "xtytz" in the top row of the input file.

What is the *correct* syntax to add a tab between the entries x,y, and z?

Thanks!

---

**Update:**
Two suggestions ended up working here:

1. using an actual tab as a "character" between x,y,and z

   `sed -i '1s/^/x y   z\n/' INPUTFILE.txt`
2. Using \t, but without the `'` surrounding it... Just drop it in!

   `sed -i '1s/^/x\ty\tz\n/' INPUTFILE.txt`

**Big thanks to all for input.**

Comment: You have to _insert_ (`i`) not _substitute_ (`s`)

Comment: agreed. [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) has lots of commands, not just `s///`

Comment: If you're using a `sed` without the GNU escape extensions (including `\t`), simply put *an actual tab* in your string.

Comment: Using an actual tab did indeed work!!! If you had submitted this as an answer I probably would have marked it as the final answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second try is almost correct. Just delete `'` separating `\t` (GNU sed 4.2.1)

```
sed -i '1s/^/x\ty\tz\n/' INPUTFILE.txt
```

However, answer suggested by glenn jackman seems to be more elegant.

Comment: This works great! I think I was getting confused with the spurious `'` because of the syntax I was using with awk elsewhere... THANKS

Answer (score 2):

This works with my sed (GNU sed 4.2.1): there's a newline immediately after the backslash

```
seq 5 | sed '1i\
a\tb\tc'
```

```
a   b   c
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: The _backslash-end-of-line_ is not even mandatory: `sed '1ia\tb\tc'` will work as expected (with GNU sed 4.2.1 too)